# How to convert datatype string to file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python 2.7.5

```
f = open("a.txt", "r")
sf = str(f)
```

I try to convert the string to the type(file). how can I convert st to the original f?

Comment: Please elaborate your question :/

Comment: "I try to convert the string to the type(file)" - that makes no sense. Are you trying to read a file? Converting a string to a file is nonsense that could be interpreted any of a number of ways.

Comment: You don't convert it, you simply write it to the file

Comment: It looks like we're already seeing 3 interpretations of the question. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? What is the end result that you would like.

Comment: PLEASE, Explain more. when you do   f = open("a.txt", "r") ,,  It creates file object i.e "f" .. you can not convert file object f into str.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wat.

If you talking about reading and writing a file, here is an example.

```
f = open("a.txt", "r")
sf = f.read()
f.close()

sf += "some more text"
f = open("a.txt", "w")
f.write(sf)
f.close()
```

Comment: Yes!! You are right!! I just make a mistake to misunderstanding the function to read files. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you can provide some more information about what you're trying to do I could help you better.

The string representation of the file object isn't very useful. You'd probably want to open it with the read() function.

```
f.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you looking for `f.name`